# How to use Select Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have database as follow :

```
npw  | sales_name | sales_type | Region |
-----------------------------------------
  1  |    Rob     | private 1  |   1    |
  2  |    Cait    | private 2  |   2    |
  3  |    Blue    | public     |   4    |
  4  |    ReD     | public     |   3    |
  5  |    Max     | private 1  |   2    |
```

and i want to make it look like :

```
region| private 1  | private 2  | public     |
-----------------------------------------------
  1   |     -      |      -     |      -     |
  2   |     -      |      -     |      -     |
  3   |     -      |      -     |      -     |
  4   |     -      |      -     |      -     |
```

so i want to distinct Region column as rows and distinct sales_type column as column header. In the future there's a possibility for new sales_type to be added. **What SQL Query for it & make new sales_type added automatically to the new column header?**

Comment: pick a database please

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using ? mysql , sql-server, oracle ? Tag the question accordingly.

Comment: How many sales_type can have only 3 as per the data ?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish such result by **CASE WHEN** AND **GROUP BY**

```
SELECT 
     Region,
     CASE 
         WHEN sales_type = 'private 1' 
         THEN sales_type 
         ELSE '-' END AS 'private 1',
    CASE 
        WHEN sales_type = 'private 2' 
        THEN sales_type  
        ELSE '-' END AS 'private 2',
   CASE 
        WHEN sales_type = 'public' 
        THEN sales_type  
        ELSE '-' END AS 'public'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Region;
```

Comment: so i have to edit query everytime new sales_type added ? like private 3.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you have other sales_type. @NamikazeSheena

Comment: theres a posibility .

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
select Region, 
   case when sales_type in('private 1') then sales_name else '' end  private1, 
   case when sales_type in('private 2') then sales_name else '' end privat2, 
   case when sales_type in('public') then sales_name else '' end public
from Table1
```

check into [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c523f/2)